# Why does describe().dtype and .dtype return different values in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a jupyter notebook from kaggle and when I download it to my local machine it breaks because of some wierd datatype behaviour.

```
train = pd.read_csv('../dataset/train.csv')


print(train["BsmtFinSF2"].dtype, train["BsmtFinSF2"].describe().dtype)
>>> ​int64 float64
```

Can anyone explain why these values are different?

The .csv is available:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=train.csv

Comment: what's wrong with this?

Comment: I can read the csv into pandas and run describe without any issues. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Why should they be same? `df.dtype` gives dtype of `df`, while `df.describe().dtype` gives you a new dataframe with count, std, mean, min, 25% etc which can be float.

Comment: There is something else happening further on in the code where one of my variables is getting split into categories when it should be integers-- still haven't figured it out but it is not this that is the proble,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain this

```
lst=[1,2,3]

#creating a dataframe from above list
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)

df[0].dtype #will give int64 as the elements of the column are int

df.describe()  #or df[0].describe() will give details about it like mean ,count,std min ,max etc which can be float.

df[0].describe().dtype # will give float64 as I explained earlier(datatype of above quantities
```

in the same way, you have the "train" data frame and you are exploring the "BsmtFinSF2" column which is of "int" type but the describe method gives "float64" as the details of the describe method can be float.

I think I explained in the simplest way

Comment: Thanks! I so the dtype from describe is really useless

Comment: ya kind of but the properties it shows are very important.keep going !!

Answer (score 1):

The [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) calculates statistics such as mean or standard deviation, and these kind of values will be very likely float valued even for integer valued data.

In school, people get integer valued grades, from 4 to 10. Yet,  they *describe* their school success with mean, such as 8.76, which is a *float*.